# Send variable to the user profile in Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I'am developing a module for Drupal which provides a login form and after submission user cURL to login in with those credentials on another website.

If all goes well, the module redirects the user to their profile and should present the information cURL fetched. This is where things go wrong.

What I'm trying to do is get the `$account` variable through the username. This is all in the `module_name_form_submit` function:

```
$account = user_load(array('name' => check_plain($user)));
```

And then append the data I want to display to it:

```
$account->content['module_name'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Module Title'),
    '#values' => get_info()
    );
```

If I do a `print_r` before the redirect, sure enough, the data is there as it should. But after the redirect:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = "users/{$user}";
```

I no longer have access to that same data. So the question is, how can I set that variable in a permanent way and access it after the redirect in the user profile page? (I'm trying to avoid sessions).

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: What kind of values do you need to pass into the user page? a string?

Comment: p.s: try asking at here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ i bet you'll get more luck

Comment: I want to pass an array. Then I can present that information using a tpl file. Thanks @DaNieL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about use variable_set($name, $value); According to your question:

```
variable_set('module_name_variable', $account);
```

When you need to access the data  use variable_get($name, $default); As per your question:

```
variable_get('module_name_variable');
```

please let me know if it works for you.

Thanks

Comment: It worked. I used `variable_set('var_name', the_array);` and then I implemented a hook_user function so after the redirect I can just do a `variable_get('var_name')` and get all that data. Thanks :-)

Comment: Although this approach works it is not the best way, since `variable_get/set/etc` clears all cache which will slow down your site and fill up the variables table. So I guess I'll have to go with sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the  [value form element](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#value) to add the user value to your form.

```
$form['userdata'] = array('#type' => 'value', 
                     '#value' => $user_load(array('name' => check_plain($user)));
```

I think this may do what you are looking for in a 'drupalish' way.

Hope it helps, good-luck!

Comment: Not sure if it helps. But I'll take a closer look into it... Thanks.

Comment: Value element is internal to drupal, it is better than a hidden fied even.  If you have to pass an array, you will need to serialize it first.